# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException on a entity I'm not saving

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

there is a "insane" error on my spring boot application. I have two entities Arrecadacao and ArrecadacaoTest. They are mapped each with different tables. As you can see in the example, I'm trying to save an ArrecadacaoTest object.
I don't no why, but If I get an Arrecadacao object, set an attribute and DON'T SAVE it, I get an error saving ArrecadacaoTest.
They don't have any relation with each other.

In addition to it, it seems that the same code works at another computers.

Oracle database, java open jdk 1.8. What more can I say?

```
public void testeMulta(int idAit, int nrAnoAit) {
        Arrecadacao multa = multasSrv.getMulta(idAit, nrAnoAit);

        multa.setNrNossonumero("1234567890");       

        testeprsistencia();

    }

@Transactional
    public void testeprsistencia() {
        ArrecadacaoTest arrecadacaoTest = new ArrecadacaoTest();
        arrecadacaoTest.setIdArrecadacao(123457l);
        arrecadacaoTest.setNrNossonumero("1234567890");
        System.out.println(arrecadacaoTest);
        arrecadacaoTestRepository.save(arrecadacaoTest);
        System.out.println(arrecadacaoTest);
    }
```

Console:

```
2021-03-31 12:30:56.367  WARN 31103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1722, SQLState: 42000
2021-03-31 12:30:56.368 ERROR 31103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-01722: número inválido

2021-03-31 12:30:56.532 ERROR 31103 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/gttrans-api] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01722: número inválido

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:207) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1044) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1329) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3584) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3665) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1352) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar:11.2.0.3.0]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3497) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3359) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3773) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_282]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1362) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:453) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3212) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2380) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534) ~[spring-orm-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:633) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:386) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.12.RELEASE.jar:5.2.12.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at br.com.cinbesa.gttransapi.service.MultasSrv.testeMulta(MultasSrv.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
```

If I simply comment the set line, everything works

```
public void testeMulta(int idAit, int nrAnoAit) {
        Arrecadacao multa = multasSrv.getMulta(idAit, nrAnoAit);

        //multa.setNrNossonumero("1234567890");

        testeprsistencia();
```

Comment: *"DON'T SAVE it"* But you **are** saving it. You call `save()` for both of them.

Comment: Actually, If save ARRECADACAO  without setting its attribute , it works. Nevertheless, thanks , I will edit.

Comment: When you update the fields of a JPA Entity object that was retrieved from the database, the changes will automatically be saved when the transaction is committed, without you having to call `save()`. Look at the stacktrace. You'll see that it doesn't include your method calling `save()`. Instead, it includes some Spring code calling `JpaTransactionManager.doCommit()`.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, this information will help me. But it still doesn't work sinceI should be able do set  multa.setNrNossonumero("1234567890"); and save. Nevertheless will review my database and post here

Answer (score 1):

You have inconsistency between entity and table.
Column nrNossonumero is numeric, but in the entity is String.

Comment: Thanks. But is not the case. It is VARCHAR2 in the database.

Answer (score 0):

@Andreas figureit out

> When you update the fields of a JPA Entity object that was retrieved from the database, the changes will automatically be saved when the transaction is committed, without you having to call save(). Look at the stacktrace. You'll see that it doesn't include your method calling save(). Instead, it includes some Spring code calling JpaTransactionManager.doCommit()

So, my entity Arrecadacao was wrong, and for it wouldn't matter since I wasn't saving.
Thanks